# How to create a multi-column page in Google Docs (with scripting)

Tags: google-apps-script, multiple-columns, google-docs

Google Docs just recently added a feature to support multiple columns on each page. Users can go to Format -> Columns and specify the number of columns and spacing between the columns. Great for a newsletter. Before that folks used tables as a work around.

I want to write a script that will take a document on letter sized paper (8.5 x 11)and put it into 2 columns on ledger sized paper (17 x 11).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked the documentation [Extending Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs) and I think that it is not yet supported using the Google Apps Script. You can file this as a feature request.

> [**Missing Features**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#missing-features)
>
> If there is functionality missing from Apps Script that you would like to use, you can file a feature request on our [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). Please describe the specific functionality you would like to see added, as well as reasons you think it's important. If possible, include specific details about your use case and the new opportunities the feature would allow for.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this for me. I think I can get my project to work using a variety of templates having the page setup I need. Thanks again.

Comment: I filed a feature request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64184688

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem, but there seems to be a column break mentioned in the API documentation.

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#columnbreak