# Google Docs Apps Script get number of columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

On a Google Doc you can set columns from Format > Columns. Now, though, I want to access those columns from Apps Script to confirm the number of columns. I don't even need to modify them, just access. I haven't found anything that jumps out at me from the documentation, so I didn't know if there's an extension of the Document service that would allow for such.
I'm sorry not to include any code, but I have no code obvious to show. I did create a document with 2 columns to see exactly what I'm talking about. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MyttroeN4kPUm9PfYZnTe_gJqstM3Gb5q3vS3c84dNw/edit

Comment: It looks like Doc script still have no such property: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41927619/how-to-create-a-multi-column-page-in-google-docs-with-scripting

Comment: One of the recent comments there mentions the ColumnBreak Paragraph Element, but this API is one I don't know how to directly access/use.

Comment: I'm sure `ColumBreak` is not the thing you want. It's just a break symbol. You can insert it via Insert > Break > Column break. As for API, here is a sample how it can be used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68018349/removing-empty-last-page-space-tab-from-google-document-using-google-apps-scrip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

*It is possible using the [get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get) method of the [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest)*

### How to do it

1. In Apps Script, enable the [Advanced Docs Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs).
2. Use the method `get`.
3. Check the array called `content`.
4. Search an object called `sectionBreak` in each element of `content`.
5. Check that the object has the following data: `sectionBreak>sectionStyle>columnProperties`.
6. Take the length of the array `columnProperties`.
7. (keep in mind that the first occurrence of `columnProperties` is in the first element of `content`, skip it and start the loop from the second one.

### Code

```
function myFunction() {
  var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()
  var result = Docs.Documents.get(id)
  var content = result["body"]["content"]
  for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
    try {
      var cols = content[i]["sectionBreak"]["sectionStyle"]["columnProperties"]
      console.log('number of columns: ' + cols.length)
    } catch (error) {
    }

  }
}
```

### Reference

- [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest)
- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Advanced Docs Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/docs)

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping there was *something* like this in the advanced service

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the advanced service using try-catch:

```
function numCols(table) {
  cols = 0;
  table = table.asTable();
  while (true) {
    try {
      table.getColumnWidth(cols);
      cols++;
    } catch {break;}
  }
  return cols;
}
```