# Google Apps Script to set Doc (not spreadsheet) columns to 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

*Can't find the answer to this to save my life!*

## I need a way to accomplish the following, but through a script:

- "Format > Columns > 1"

I can't figure out how to reproduce this GUI task, but in script.... I can't even search for it, as all the spreadsheet stuff get's in the way - even if I go all advanced search and try "exact strings", -thing, +that...

## Anyone got a clue what method I'm looking for?

*Cheers!*

Comment: How about `DocumentApp.Attribute.width` assigned to a cell in a table. [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)

Comment: May I try to clarify? You have a text in a Google document that has been formatted into multiple columns. You goal is to change the column formatting from multiple columns to a single column (that is, no columns at all). You are looking for a way to do this by script. Is that correct?

Comment: Have you read [How to create a multi-column page in Google Docs (with scripting)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41971108/1330560)? Though this topic is dated from 2017, the referenced [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64184688) is still live, as is the possible Documents API workaround.